# NSTextField and controlTextDidEndEditing

Tags: objective-c, textfield, nstextfield

I have a class 'EditingField' extending the NSTextField. The textfields are variables in my AppDelegate.

I wish to do something after the user has ended editing the textfield. Apparently i am to use the `controlTextDidEndEditing` or `textFieldDidEndEditing`. Which one am i to use?

Furthermore where exactly am i to implement the methods and how do i set a delegate if that is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using **NSTextField** (i.e. are developing for **OS X**) then you'd use `controlTextDidEndEditing`. If you're using **UITextField** (i.e. are developing for **iOS**) then you'd be using `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

The delegate methods can be implemented in any class you wish, in a very small application perhaps even in the app delegate, otherwise you'd probably implement them in the controller responsible for the part of the UI containing the text field.

To set a delegate, use the  `setDelegate:` method.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand all the UITextField references i encountered! So do i get this right: i add `-(void) controlTextDidEndEditing...` to the app delegate (or later to it's proper controller class but not to get things more complicated) and i use something like `[myTextField setDelegate: self]` ?

Comment: That's correct. Also, when using `UITextField`, the delegate must conform to the [UITextFieldDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html), so you'll need to add `<UITextFieldDelegate>` to the interface of your class, otherwise you'll get a compiler warning (you don't have to implement any of the other delegate methods though, they're all optional).